# Save multiple selected rows in UITableView

Tags: objective-c

I have a table where I can select multiple rows in the `UITableView`. When I press “Done” I want it to add these into three different arrays. At the moment it will only save the first selected row. How can I make it save all selected rows in the `UITableView`?

Here is my “Done” button method:

```
-(IBAction)songsDone:(id)sender{

    selectedName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [selectedName addObject:video.title];

    selectedAuthor = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [selectedAuthor addObject:video.author];

    selectedLink = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [selectedLink addObject:video.thumb];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    SongsViewController *songsViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SongsViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:songsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initializing code to ViewDidLoad method like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [selectedName addObject:video.title];
    [selectedAuthor addObject:video.author];
    [selectedLink addObject:video.thumb];
    return self;
}
```

and simply add values like below

```
-(IBAction)songsDone:(id)sender{


[selectedName addObject:video.title];


[selectedAuthor addObject:video.author];


[selectedLink addObject:video.thumb];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
SongsViewController *songsViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SongsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:songsViewController animated:YES];
```

}